# How to run a python file .py in jupiter-notebook?

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

how can I run a python .py file in google colab with jupyternotebook?

Comment: `!python file.py` should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your great help, I also figured it out later.